# How to get kubernetes cluster view?

Tags: docker, block, kubernetes

I have Kubernetes cluster in which Replicationcontroller, Service, Endpoints, Pods etc are running. I just want to get overall view of kubernetes cluster as a block diagram.

can any one help to complete this requirement?

Answer (score 1):

Check out the [Kubernetes Dashboard](https://github.com/kubernetes/dashboard). It isn't quite a block diagram, but it provides a good view into what is going on in your cluster.

There is also the [Kubernetes UI](https://github.com/kubernetes-ui/graph), which doesn't have as much active development, but at one point was able to show a really cool graph of your Kubernetes internals.

Comment: Solution which you gave that is excellent, it would be better if you provide configuration steps as well. Thanks in advance.

Comment: For the Kubernetes Dashboard, you can run it (or make sure it is already running) by going through the [Usage](https://github.com/kubernetes/dashboard#usage) guide. More info can be found in the [Kubernetes docs](http://kubernetes.io/docs/user-guide/ui/). I don't know as much about the Kubernetes UI.